# Synchronized keyword not working as expected when monitor object is shared between multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am practicing java multi threading and concurrency. So I am currently working on wait() and notify() functionality. I have created below code

```
public class WaitAndNotifyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object testString = new Object();
        RunnableImplTest runnableImplTest = new RunnableImplTest(testString);
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnableImplTest);
            System.out.println("Created thread " + thread.getName());
            thread.start();
        }
        
        synchronized (testString) {
            testString.notify();
        }

    }
    
    private static class RunnableImplTest implements Runnable{
        
        private Object str;
        
        public RunnableImplTest(Object str) {
            this.str = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized (str) {
                    System.out.println("Sending in waiting state for thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    str.wait();
                    System.out.println("Waiting completion for thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Got the control for "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

I have created this code to check how notify() selects the one thread from the list of waiting threads to allow further execution.

Now I am getting below output for the above code

```
Created thread Thread-0
Created thread Thread-1
Created thread Thread-2
Sending in waiting state for thread Thread-0
Created thread Thread-3
Sending in waiting state for thread Thread-1
Created thread Thread-4
Sending in waiting state for thread Thread-2
Sending in waiting state for thread Thread-3
Sending in waiting state for thread Thread-4
Waiting completion for thread Thread-0
Got the control for Thread-0
```

According to my code I was expecting that synchronized keyword should lock on the monitor object for thread-X and any other thread should not be allowed to enter that block in their own instances of `RunnableImplTest` as I have shared the monitor object across multiple threads.

Comment: Not sure, but ist the object really shared between the Threads?

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in the JavaDoc for [Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)) (note added emphasis):

> This method causes the current thread (referred to here as T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then **to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object**.

Note that this is required: how else could the main thread execute

```
    synchronized (testString) {
        testString.notify();
    }
```

if the lock on `testString` was still held by any of the threads that you started.

BTW `testString` is a terrible name: it is not a string, it doesn't have anything to do with tests, it distracts from understanding its purpose.

Comment: Yeah sorry, initially it was string type, changed it to an object type but forgot to change the name. Thank you for the clarification on the wait() method.

Comment: You should also note that there is no guaranty that the `notify` call is made after at least one `wait` has been made. It possible that the main thread executes the `notify` call before any thread starts to wait, ending up with all threads waiting forever. But it’s also possible that `wait` returns *spuriously*, without a matching `notify` call. In other words, pay attention to the “*The recommended approach to waiting is to check the condition being awaited in a `while` loop around the call to `wait`…*” part of the documentation. Which requires you to define a checkable condition…

Answer (score 0):

The `wait()` method relinquishes the lock held by the thread on that object.

From [`Object#wait(long,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)):

> This method causes the current thread (referred to here as T) to place itself in the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all synchronization claims on this object.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the clarification.